# RESTful API response for data transfer objects

Tags: rest, httpresponse, dto

I have this following scenario in my application. I am logged in as a user and i create a group. There is a REST api for creating the group (POST /groups/api/v1/groups) and getting the group details (GET /groups/api/v1/groups/{group id})

The response returned on success is not just the json representation of the group resource. Its a DTO which contains a lot of other information  (to avoid multiple calls to the server)

For instance, the response can include

1. Actions that can be performed on the group (for ex: inviting a user to the group) and the corresponding urls that need to be hit for each action
2. Count of members in the group.
3. Recent activity in the group
4. Member information

etc

Right now the only client using the REST api's is the UI which needs additional information. If the APIs are exposed to developers later, they may not need all the information being returned. How do we handle rest responses in such scenarios where we have to return DTO's which contain more information?

Is it a good design to be returning dto's in rest response for GET or should be avoided?

Comment: Do you have ways to lock down roles or allow roles to specific api methods?

Comment: The clients should not break because they are being sent extra data, and ideally should be able to handle not getting the data they expect (display an error for that field, opposed to crashing the entire program). You server is wasting everyone's time if it is sending more data than it has to. The requests should detail what information they are asking for, this can be done via the URI of as a part of the request body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if you accept the fact that RESTful HTTP is noisy. The design compensation for the noise is caching, which you should try to use as much as you can to save server hits. A well-cached application can use multiple resources, rather than one large resource, because many of the requests will not ever leave the client.

As far as your specific question, use the `expand` query parameter to identify what child objects to include. You can further specify what properties of that child to include. For example,

```
GET /groups/api/v1/groups/12345
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "The Magnificent Seven",
    "location": {
        "self": "/groups/api/v1/locations/43"
    }
}

GET /groups/api/v1/groups/12345?expand=location
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "The Magnificent Seven",
    "location": {
        "self": "/groups/api/v1/locations/43",
        "longitude": "24°01′N",
        "latitude": "104°40′W"
    }
}

GET /groups/api/v1/groups/12345?expand=location[latitude]
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "The Magnificent Seven",
    "location": {
        "self": "/groups/api/v1/locations/43",
        "latitude": "104°40′W"
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good approach. I found similar best practices when designing RESTful API's here http://saipraveenblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/rest-api-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

Well giving more data than required can prove to be harmful and you need to start explaining everyone why you are giving so much data. You can have a query param that is secret to a subset of users say "alldetails=true" which will give the full DTO.

If you are using Java with codehaus or some other JSON utility on the REST server you can specify what elements to expose by using a mixin. codehaus has "addMixInAnnotations()" for that.

A good REST response for GET should have an identifier, required details and URLs in JSON or XML.

Comment: The idea of that `alldetails=true` jut being secret is a bit odd to me, it should just be a permissions thing if it works or not. I'd be careful saying a good REST response should have JSON or XML, the format of the data really does not matter.

Comment: Ya... My answers based on most of the REST implementation which are HTTP based with JSON or XML responses.

Comment: Sure, but just to be clear, REST absolutely does not have to be HTTP with JSON or XML, it just almost always will be.